# Optimal way to convert from 16-bit linear PCM audio to 32-bit floating point in C/C+?

Tags: c++, c, audio, core-audio

What is the optimal way to convert from 16-bit linear PCM audio to 32-bit floating point in C or C++?

Comment: Optimal in what sense? The most efficient way?

Comment: One sample at a time, very little point in optimizing this.  Or by using one of the many available audio support libraries.

Comment: Since you appear to be developing for iOS and/or MacOSX, the [Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) is worth looking at.

Comment: Have you profiled it to ensure that it's where your app is actually spending its time?

Comment: The fastest is probably `vDSP_vflt16` followed by `vDSP_vsdiv`

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
std::vector<int16_t> PCM = foo();
std::vector<float> audio(begin(PCM), end(PCM));
```

You can expect this to be 1000x realtime.